# How to update a .net windows service from a central location

Tags: .net, deployment, windows-services, process

We have built a **.NET Windows Service** that we install on client PCs to monitor and upload data (via a web service) from those PCs. I am looking for a way to **update the windows service on all client PCs centrally** -- without having to remote into each store.

> Here are some specifics (although, I
>   don't think this really matters):
>
> - Windows Service: .NET version 2 (due to client PC constraints) -
>     VB.NET
> - Web Service: .NET version 4 - VB.NET
> - Client PCs OS: Win2000 to Win7, POSReady, WEPOS

**Some extra information**

- We have a setup file that works very well, but we need to remote into each store to run it. And there are 100s of stores!
- We had considered putting the setup file on an FTP site, but was told that Windows Embedded OSes did not support FTP, so we might send the file via a web service
- Once every minute each windows service calls a web service method that returns an some XML, which can be used to send an instruction to update the web service.

This seems like a standard problem that developers would have needed to solve many times already. If anyone has any advice or can suggest a process that they use, it would really help us.

**UPDATE**

- I can change both the Windows service and the web service to add this new updating functionality
- Looks like I have a way to get the setup file (downloading from a web service method), but what about running it? How do I run the installer and then make sure that the Windows service has shut down? Does the installer do that or the Windows service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a web service, you can  add a method for the update.

Create a little update installer or application (that you would run locally).
Then in the web service add a method that returns a Stream or byte[] array.
In the web service's method read the binary installer file into the byte[] array or stream, and send it to the client.

Then have the client save that stream into a file, and now you have the installer on the client machine.
All that's left to do is run that process and update the service.

Comment: Good answer, if he already had such a thing built into his app. My bet is he doesn't, but he will after going through the headache of a manual push of the patch installer or an updater program that will grab the patch.

Comment: build it in the app now, update them all manually (send them all the install or something) then next time you don't have to worry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and you are right: I can change my app, so the client can save a file from a web service. But what about AFTER downloading. How do I run the installer from a program that needs to be closed to be upgraded?

Comment: You run the program from the service (or updater), and make your installer close the service.

Answer (score 1):

If the patch is an MSI package, you can use Active Directory to push out the update to computers in the same network under the control of the AD server. The update will then run immediately or on next startup.

You can push the packages yourself, but there has to be some transport mechanism that is listening at the other end, controlled by a program with sufficient smarts and privileges to perform the update automatically.

Barring AD, this is probably your best shot: use ordinary network file shares to push the update down to the client. The client computer MUST be running, but it can be at the welcome screen. Then, place a batch file in the Documents & Users/All Users/Start Menu/Startup folder that will perform a "canned install" of the MSI (basically telling the MSI to perform a silent install with default installation parameters). On the next user login, the batch file will run, performing the install. The MSI should probably clean up the batch file afterward. If you can remotely access the client computer's registry (I HIGHLY doubt that), you can put the batch file in a temp directory somewhere and place a reference to it in the RunOnce registry folder.

Going through this rigamarole once will probably teach you to structure apps like this to check for and download their own updates via a known web service, or set them up to use ClickOnce deployment (this makes installation directories messy, but update deployment gets MUCH simpler).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Re "...will probably teach you to structure apps like this to check for and download their own updates via a known web service", I can change the app, so please tell me more about using known web services to update my app.

Comment: Basically, the pattern is that your application, when it opens, should call a simple web service that will tell it the latest released version of the software, and compare it to its own. If they differ, call a second web service that will download and run the update package.